# Kurdish font convert to symbol in weka software

Tags: text, weka, text-processing

[image]Kurdish font is like Arabic and Persian when I put Kurdish documents into weka after apply "StringtoWordvector" filter the text change to symbol as shown in the above picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux uses UTF-8 by default and will have no problem displaying languages other than English. If you are on Windows (which uses a different encoding for historic reasons), please have a look at the FAQ [Can I process UTF-8 datasets or files?](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/faqs/can_i_process_utf8_datasets_or_files/)

Comment: Thanks so much, my problem is solved by using your link. your support is highly appreciated.